# Handling error scenarios in Spring REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, exception

IMHO exceptions are for exceptional cases. Exceptions should not be thrown if the scenario can be handled without exception.

Creating exception takes at least 1ms and it comes with a performance impact. So which is the best way to handle error scenario?

**Scenario#1:**

```
ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
 if(order.items == null)
   return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
 ...
}
```

**Scenario#2:**
Spring provides @ControllerAdvice and ResponseEntityExceptionHandler as mentioned in [Error Handling for REST with Spring](http://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

```
ResponseEntity createOrder(@RequestBody Order order){
     if(order.items == null)
       throw new CustomException();
     ...
    }

@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = { CustomException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "Error";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using exceptions without stack trace? They are more efficient for such cases

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @xsx4u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally i would choose scenario #2 because it's centralized. Later you would be able to change response code for that particular exception or add some verbose logging. In terms of performance scenario #1 is obviously faster, but i would neglect that time difference

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the particular case you have I would use Hibernate to validate and not let the invalid data into the controller to start with.

```
 public class Order {
 ...
     @NotNull
     @NotEmpty
     private List<Integer> items;
 }
```

It will automatically create 400 error for the case items is either empty or null (internally uses exceptions though).

To handle other exceptions I would use `@ExceptionHandler` as you have there, either per controller or via a `@ControllerAdvice` (to catch globally).

> Creating exception takes at least 1ms

Exceptions are slow, but not that slow.

Comment: The input is validated by business rules and the error status is returned based on that. My question is that we can handle these error and validation cases ourself in the normal program flow, instead of throwing the exception and handling it.

Comment: I would still prefer exceptions in this case. It allows better design, eg. extracting the validation logic into a Validator class. Also as the other answer pointed out, the response format is centralized.